# My search bar is not centered on the nav, but when opening my sidebar it is centered on the navbar. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in web dev so I have a lot of doubts in css and javascript. So a very annoying error is occurring in my navigation bar involving the search bar. In my mobile optimization, when I click on my search bar it expands to 100% width and excludes all components of my navbar, but when I do that, my search bar goes to the top of the nav as in the picture:

[my search bar without clicking on the button to open the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi8CH.png)

However, in my navbar there is a button to open a sidebar, and when I press to open it and close, magically my searchbar when I click there, it is "centralized"

[my searchbar with the click on the button to open the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI3pP.png)

How can I resolve this so that both situations are always centered in my navbar. I'm using html, css, js and a bit of bootstrap. My codes are below:

html:

```
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    
    <div class="logo">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    </div>

    <div class="search-bar-container">
      <i class="fa fa-search search-icon"></i>
      <button id="pesquisar" type="button" onclick="buscarLocal()"
        style="border: none; background: none; position: absolute; left: 10px;"></button>
      <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="search-bar" placeholder="" list="myList">
      <datalist id="myList"></datalist>
    </div>


    <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <h2>Olá, <span id="userName"></span></h2>
      <a href="#" onclick="exibirMeusMarcadores()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMarkersModal">Meus Marcadores</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#configModal">Configurações</a>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <a href="#" onclick="signOut()">Sair</a>
      <button id="signInButton" class="btn btn-primary ml-2" onclick="signInWithGoogle()">
        <i class="fab fa-google"></i> Entrar com o Google
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div id="overlay"></div>

  </div>
```

css:

```
@media (max-width:600px) { 

    .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}

    .logo {
        width:auto; 
        text-align:center; 
    }
    
    .search-bar-container { 
      width: 80px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      }

    .navbar {
      display: flex; 
      justify-content: center; 
      align-items: center; 
    }

    
  .search-bar {
    transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Adicione a animação de largura */
    width: 80px; /* Largura inicial */
    margin: 0; /* Remova a margem para que a barra de pesquisa ocupe toda a altura da navbar */
  }

    .search-icon {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px; /* Ajuste a posição esquerda do ícone conforme necessário */
      color: #191919;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    .search-bar-container:focus-within {
      /* Adicione o estilo para expandir a caixa de pesquisa aqui */
      width: 100%;
    }

  .search-bar-container:focus-within .search-bar {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #userDropdown, #signInButton {
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
      display: none;
    }

    #main {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
```

js:

```
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#searchInput');

searchInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    buscarLocal();
  }
});

searchInput.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
    // Adiciona a classe 'hide' aos itens da navbar
    document.querySelector('.logo').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('#userDropdown').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('#signInButton').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('#main').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('#pesquisar').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('.search-icon').classList.add('hide');
    document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.add('sidebar-open')
  } 
});

searchInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
    document.querySelector('#userDropdown').classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#signInButton').classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('.logo').classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#main').classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#pesquisar').classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.remove('sidebar-open')
    document.querySelector('.search-icon').classList.remove('hide');
  
  } 
});

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';

  document.querySelector('.logo').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.search-icon').classList.toggle('hide');
  document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.toggle('hide');
  document.querySelector('.openbtn').style.display = 'none';

  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";

  document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.add('sidebar-open');
  document.querySelector('#pesquisar').classList.add('hide');
  document.querySelector('.search-icon').classList.add('hide');
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';

  document.querySelector('.logo').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.openbtn').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.search-icon').classList.remove('hide');
  document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.remove('hide');

  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";

  document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.remove('sidebar-open');
  document.querySelector('#pesquisar').classList.remove('hide');
  document.querySelector('.search-icon').classList.remove('hide');
}
```

Thank you for your attention, if you can, point me to reading materials on the subject. Thanks again

At first I tried to remove all animations, but without success.

After that, I tried to make `search-bar:focus` expand according to certain numbers of px. However, doing this to my navigation bar without pressing the .openbtn button, it was centralized, but by clicking on .openbtn and closing the sidebar, the search bar when accessing it, was misaligned to the right.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use CSS flexbox for better control over the layout of elements in your navigation panel. Here are a few ideas on how to achieve this:

> ***Use Flexbox for Aligning Elements:***

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; /* Distribute elements on both sides */
    align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment of elements */
}
```

> ***Remove Inline Width Style for the Search Bar:***

Instead, set the width of the search bar in CSS. This ensures consistent behavior in all situations:

```
.search-bar {
    transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 80px; /* Initial width */
    margin: 0;
}
```

> ***Adjust JavaScript for Opening/Closing the Sidebar:***

Make sure that the JavaScript for opening/closing the sidebar also adjusts the classes and styles of the search bar. Here's the updated code for the openNav and closeNav functions:

```
function openNav() {
    // ... (rest of the code)
    document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.add('sidebar-open');
}

function closeNav() {
    // ... (rest of the code)
   document.querySelector('.search-bar').classList.remove('sidebar-open');
}
```

With this approach, the search panel should remain centered and consistent regardless of the sidebar's state. If you're still experiencing issues, I recommend gradually debugging your code and using browser developer tools to identify which part of the code is causing unwanted behavior.